# NodeJS and PM2 in cluster mode on Windows Server - after heap memory error cluster is not starting up

Tags: node.js, windows, server, pm2

I'm running a NodeJS (Strapi) application on Windows server via PM2 in Cluster mode (using the ecosystem.config file).

```
module.exports = {
      apps: [
        {
          name: 'Primary',
          instances: "1",
          exec_mode: "cluster",
          script: '../Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
          args: 'run start:win',
          node_args: "--max-old-space-size=4096"
        },
        {
           name: 'eplica',
           instances: "-1",
           exec_mode: "cluster",
           script: '../Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
           args: 'run start:win',
           node_args: "--max-old-space-size=4096"
         },
      ],
    };
```

As soon as the Primary app crashes with heap memory error, the cluster instantly stops responding.
`PM2 list` still shows both apps as Online, however the app returns 502 as I try to access if via browser.
Also the --max-old-space-size setting seemingly does not do anything, since my app crashes when around 2Gb memory is consumed with this setting or without it.

Could someone please advise - what am I doing wrong and how can I get the cluster to remain operational, while that Primary app recovers (and how to force it to recover)?

There are no logs available in the Cluster mode, so I'm a little be lost now.

When I launch one of the apps in fork mode, it still crashes with the same heap memory error, however PM2 in this case recovers it and automatically restarts it.